# How to Convert a Class Component to a Functional Component in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

I always work with functional components as they give me more flexibility and i can use hooks with them. I have a drop down menu functionality that is coded using the class component. Now i need to convert this to a functional component as i need to do some backend work for some of the menu buttons, such as logout and name and so on.

I tried to convert it my self but it ended with always keeping to Modal open and giving me an error that reads `" this.props.toggle is not a function at Dropdown.toggle"` and it slowed down my website incredibly.

How can i make the below code equivalent to a functional component?

Class Component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {
  Dropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem,
} from "reactstrap";
import { withRouter, Link } from "react-router-dom";

//i18n
import { withTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class ProfileMenu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      menu: false,
      name: "Admin",
    }
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this)
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      menu: !prevState.menu,
    }))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Dropdown
          isOpen={this.state.menu}
          toggle={this.toggle}
          className="d-inline-block"
        >
          <DropdownToggle
            className="btn header-item"
            id="page-header-user-dropdown"
            tag="button"
          >
            <span className="d-none d-xl-inline-block ms-1">
              {this.state.name}
            </span>
            <i className="mdi mdi-chevron-down d-none d-xl-inline-block" />
          </DropdownToggle>
          <DropdownMenu className="dropdown-menu-end">
            <DropdownItem tag="a" href="/">
              Dashboard
            </DropdownItem>
            <div className="dropdown-divider" />
            <Link to="/logout" className="dropdown-item">
              <i className="bx bx-power-off font-size-16 align-middle me-1 text-danger" />
              <span>{this.props.t("Logout")}</span>
            </Link>
          </DropdownMenu>
        </Dropdown>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

ProfileMenu.propTypes = {
  t: PropTypes.any,
  success: PropTypes.string
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const { success } = state.Profile
  return { success }
}

export default withRouter(
  connect(mapStateToProps, {})(withTranslation()(ProfileMenu))
)
```

Below code is how i tried to convert it

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {
  Dropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem,
} from "reactstrap";
import { withRouter, Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import firebase from "../../../firebase"
function ProfileMenu(){
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const history = useHistory();
  const logout = () => {
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
      console.log("logged out")
      history.push("/login");
    }).catch(function(error) {
      // An error happened.
      console.log("didnt logout")
    });
  }
  const openModal = () => {
    setIsOpen(true);
  };

  const closeModal = () => {
    setIsOpen(false);
  };


    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Dropdown
          isOpen={isOpen}
          onClick={openModal}
          toggle={""}
          className="d-inline-block"
        >
          <DropdownToggle
            // onClick={openModal}
            className="btn header-item"
            id="page-header-user-dropdown"
            tag="button"
          >
            <span className="d-none d-xl-inline-block ms-1">
              {/* {this.state.name} */}
            </span>
            <i className="mdi mdi-chevron-down d-none d-xl-inline-block" />
          </DropdownToggle>
          <DropdownMenu className="dropdown-menu-end">
         
            <DropdownItem tag="a" href="/">
              Dashboard
            </DropdownItem>
      
            <div className="dropdown-divider" />
            <button className="dropdown-item" onClick={logout}>
              <i className="bx bx-power-off font-size-16 align-middle me-1 text-danger" />
              <span>Logout</span>
            </button>
          </DropdownMenu>
        </Dropdown>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  
}
export default ProfileMenu
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the toggle as function, you are instead passing string, also you can directly toggle state value, it will make the component re-render, try the following code and let me know if this helps.

Just for better visibility I am removing the class names, so that code looks clean.

You can also use the `useContext` instead of using redux.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Dropdown, DropdownToggle, DropdownMenu, DropdownItem } from "reactstrap";
import { withRouter, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import firebase from "../../../firebase";

type Prop = {
  name: string;
};
const ProfileMenu: React.FC<Prop> = ({ name }) => {
  const [menu, setMenu] = useState(false);
  const history = useHistory();
  const logout = () => {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signOut()
      .then(function () {
        history.push("/login");
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("didnt logout");
      });
  };
  return (
    <Dropdown isOpen={menu} toggle={() => setMenu(!menu)} >
      <DropdownToggle >
        <span >{name}</span>
        <i className="mdi mdi-chevron-down d-none d-xl-inline-block" />
      </DropdownToggle>
      <DropdownMenu >
        <DropdownItem tag="a" href="/">
          Dashboard
        </DropdownItem>
        <div className="dropdown-divider" />
        <button onClick={logout}>
          <i className="bx bx-power-off font-size-16 align-middle me-1 text-danger" />
          <span>Logout</span>
        </button>
      </DropdownMenu>
    </Dropdown>
  );
};

export default withRouter(ProfileMenu);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const ProfileMenu = (props) => {

  const [name, setName] = useState('aaa'); // define and initialize name state
  
  ....

  let myName = name; // call name state

  ....

  let toggle = props.toggle; //call toggle props

}
```

I hope this will be helpful for you. Thanks.

Comment: Still didn't work. This wont convert everything to a functional component